# How can i check if my host command in script got a valid ip

Tags: shell, scripting

Suppose we only have 1 parameter

```
host $1
```

How can I check if the above command will give me an answer or:

```
Host $1 not found (NXDOMAIN)
```

and instead of showing an error not found, I would like to show just a `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`host` will exit 1 if it is unable to resolve your input so you can use an if construct:

```
if ! host "$1" | grep -v 'not found'; then
  printf '%s\n' '-'
fi
```

---

We are using `!` to test if the command fails (since I assume you want to just print the output as normal if it passes).  `host` sends the `not found` error to stdout instead of stderr so we can't just hide stdout.  This is why I am piping the host command into `grep -v 'not found'` this will hide the not found error if it exists and still exit 1, causing the if construct to print `-`.  If it does not find `not found` it will exit 0.

Comment: i dont know if i type anything wrong but now it just prints both of them:

Host $1 not found (NXDOMAIN)
-

Comment: @ThodorisDiamantidis: Yes sorry, it appears as if `host` sends errors to `stdout` instead of `stderr`

Comment: Ok this solution seems to work just fine thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Would exit status be sufficient? You can incorporate the `$?`, the exit status of last command, even if you silenced the output. For `host` exit status 0 is success and 1 is error

```
[17:54] [ws ~] $ host 127.0.0.112 1>&2 >/dev/null
[17:54] [ws ~] $ echo $?
1
[17:54] [ws ~] $ host 127.0.0.1 1>&2 >/dev/null
[17:54] [ws ~] $ echo $?
0
```